Double slit experiment with electrons
Here is my understanding. In the double slit experiment, the one in which we fire one electron at a time, we see an interference pattern on the far screen as well. However, when trying to see which hole the electron passes through, the pattern disappear. Why? Well, here is what i understand. At the slits, the electron is in superposition of the two slits. Therefore, watching which hole the electron  passes through, collapses the superposition into one of two positions, consequently collapsing the interference pattern as well. That was the scenario at the slits. After the slits, the electron is in superposition of all positions on the screen. Therefore, the collapse happing at the screen due to detection will yield a position out of so many with some probility. Therefore, each time an electron reaches the screen, the superposition collapses into some specific position with some probility.
Is my understanding right?

What is your question?

My question is do I understand right?

Your understanding does not seem complete, because the statement "After the slits, the electron is in superposition of all positions on the screen." is true whether the slit was observed or not. Its just that the specific superposition is different in the two cases.

What do you mean by it is true whether the slit was observed or not? I mean, doesn't observation collapses the wavedunction? Therefore after observation the electron is no longer in superposition. And given the fact that only two positions are observed to be occupied by the electrons when the observation is made at the slits, this implies that the electron was only in superposition of two positions so to speak at the slits.

"I mean, doesn't observation collapses the wavedunction?" Yes, observation at the slits collapses the wave function into a slit position eigenstate. But slit position eigenstates are not screen position eigenstates. Therefore, any slit state will be a linear combination (so-called superposition) of screen eigenstates. The difference is in what those linear combinations are.

In quantum mechanics, the statement "x is in a superposition" is in itself meaningless. A superposition of what? For instance, a particle in a box can be in a (single) energy state, which is equal to a superposition of momentum states.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer Let me get this straight. You're saying that the state function is the same, whether at the slit or at the screen. The difference is, at the slits the state function is expanded via the slit position eigen states. However, at the screen, the same state function is now expanded via the positions on the screen eigen states, right?

No, the states are different, otherwise we would observe no difference. I'm saying that simply stating "Therefore, each time an electron reaches the screen, the superposition collapses into some specific position with some probility." is true, but true for both slit configurations and therefore too vague to explain anything. The different slit configurations give different wave functions immediately after the slits. These propagate to the sceeen, resulting in different screen superpositions, with different associated probabilities for screen detection. Hence different observed patterns.

"The different slit configurations give different wave functions immediately after the slits. These propagate to the sceeen, resulting in different screen superpositions, with different associated probabilities for screen detection. Hence different observed patterns." I mean, isn't that what i said? I mean i said the wavefunction at the slit is different from that after the slit and you implied that even more different at the screen. Therefore, the collapse at the slit yields different result compared to the result at the screen. Excuse me if I am appearing idiot

Maybe it was what you meant :) the way I read it, you gave one description of what could happen at the slit, and then an independent/disconnected description of what happens at the screen. The missing link (the way I read your post) was what connects the two, as well as some technical clarity e.g. regarding the use of the word superposition.

@MariusLadegårdMeyer If you don't mind, would you please write down a complete answer in the answer section. I'd really appreciate that.

this is a case where it's best to let the math do the talking.

This question has no answer as there is no such thing as a physical collapse process. All there is is a wave function with interference effects, which gives the probability of finding a particle.

Jack it is a very good understanding.  I like to say the EM field rules, the electron or photon is dumb.  An excited electron in the source is already creating ripples in the EM field ... long before emission.  Yes, messing with the electron after the slits changes the field ... all paths to the screen are possible.

When I first heard about wave function collapse, I didn't like it. It was Re: $\psi(x) \propto \delta(x-x_0)$ for a particle at $x_0$. So I retorted: but the wave function $\phi(p)$ just expanded to contain all $p$:
$$ \phi(p) \propto e^{ipx_0/\hbar}$$
And that is pretty much what is happening here. I'm propagating a initial plane wave (scalar for simplicity, unnormalized, $\hbar=1$):
$$ \psi_-(x, y, z) = A_(x, y)\psi_-(z) = e^{ikz-\omega t} $$
with the infinite vertical $y$-direction slits at $z=0$, with finite size in $x$.
The transverse modulating function is unity:
$$A_-(x, y) = 1$$
because the incident beam is a true plane wave.
So $\psi_-(z)$ refers to the incident wave.
It spans all of $x$ and $y$. When it hits the slit-screen: bam, the wave-function undergoes an $x$-dependent collapse so that at the screen:
$$ \psi_-(z)\rightarrow \psi_0(x, z) = A_0(x)e^{ikz-\omega t} $$
where $A_0(x)$ is the aperture function representing one or two slit(s).
So the collapse occurs in this transverse modulating function:
$$A_-(x, y) = 1\rightarrow A_0(x) $$
What happens to $\phi_0(\vec p)$ (the momentum space version of $\psi_0$?).
It expands. It goes from
$$\phi_-(p) \propto \delta(p_x)\delta(p_y)\delta(p_z-\hbar k)$$
$$\phi_+(p) \propto \tilde A(p_x)\delta(p_y)\delta(p_z-\hbar k)$$
(in the small angle approx...no corrections on $|k|$)
where $\tilde A(p_x)$ is the Fourier transform of the aperture function $A(x)$, and that is the thing that makes the pattern on the detection screen.
That's it. Notice how I never mentioned which slit is taken?
If you do nothing, $\tilde A(p_x)$ is an interference pattern.
If you detected which slit is taken, $\tilde A(p_x)$ is a diffraction pattern (which is an expansion of the wave function).
In each case, the detected pattern is a coherent sum of the amplitudes of ALL possible paths.

The equations of motion of quantum theory don't include collapse and aren't compatible with it. To add collapse to quantum theory you have to modify the equations of motion, e.g. - spontaneous collapse theories:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
This creates various problems that haven't been solved and as a result such theories can't reproduce most of the predictions of quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Quantum theory without collapse doesn't have those problems. Quantum interference is a process where the outcome of an experiment depends on what happens to all of the possible states of the system involved in the experiment. If you copy information out of a system while it is undergoing interference that copying suppresses the interference: an effect called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Since the different possible values no longer interfere with one another they evolve independently so that you don't see the other values:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
The electron doesn't undergo interference as a result of decoherence not collapse.
